# Finding Object in Ruby on Rails (need to cancel ssh connection in Net::SSH)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, object, ssh

I have the following Port Forwarding created with [Net::SSH](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh):

```rb
def connectToCustomerSystem
  Net::SSH.start("localhost", 'myuser', :password => "password") do |ssh|
    logger.debug ssh.exec!("hostname")
    ssh.forward.local(1234, "www.capify.org", 80) 
    #ssh.loop { true } #dont use loop to directly render director/index
  end  
  render :controller => "director", :action => "index"
end
```

Now i will cancel this Connection via "ssh.forward.cancel_local(1234)" in a new, other method.

```rb
def disconnectForwarding
  ssh.forward.cancel_local(1234)
end
```

But, of course, "ssh" isnt valid in this context. How could i search all available Objects with Type "Net::SSH"? Or are there any other ways how i could quit a specific Forwarding (because in the end, there will be much Forwards for some different Users, and i dont want to kill all, just a specific one).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're trying to keep stateful Ruby objects around while interacting with Rails. This doesn't play well with the Rails "shared nothing" approach to servers.  Not only will ssh not be in scope because of the block being out of scope for your method, you will be talking to a different worker process next time.

What you need is separate longer running ruby processes in the background to manage the ssh connection.  A simple way to do this is launch a ruby script and connect to the object managing ssh using DRb.  You can then reconnect to the Ruby process managing the connection each time a request is handled and give it commands over DRb. The ssh variable might work as an instance variable inside the object you speak with over [DRb](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/drb/rdoc/DRb.html) in this case (it looks like you can set this to loop so it sticks around).

There are some terrible approaches to getting out of the scope box, like setting the variable as a thread-local variable, or searching the ObjectSpace.each_object, but those approaches are pretty bad in principal.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your Answer. But in Ruby i think i will have the same Problem - if i use one ruby-script for a couple SSH-Connections. One Method which will run the SSH Process (without the "ssh.loop" because else the SSH Process and with it the whole ruby script wouldnt finish). But if i create a ruby script (DRb) for every SSH Connection, i end up in a problem with open tcp ports, nor did i (i think i need "URI="druby://localhost:8787"" in every new script, which means i need two Ports for every SSH Connection, as you know what i mean)?

Comment: How much you are planning to scale this that you are thinking you'll be running out of tcp ports? DRb has scalability limitations. If you're shooting for > 50 simultaneous connections, DRb will cause problems. In that case, I'd look at dcell https://github.com/celluloid/dcell. In terms of the script finishing, if you close it out by calling a method, your object could have an instance variable @stop that shuts things down. You can pass that into the loop method, which takes an optional block that, when true, stops processing. Multiple processes may connect to one drb server on a single port.

Comment: Actually, I had that backwords. It stops it when the block is false, so maybe name it @active or something along those lines.